# ComponentLookupError on Dexterity types during testing

Tags: testing, plone, dexterity

I have a custom product with a number of Dexterity types, several of which are used by a setuphandler to create the site structure. This works without any issues outside of testing, but within tests it keeps failing:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [snip]
  File "/opt/ctcc_plone/src/ctcc.model/ctcc/model/setuphandlers.py", line 52, in setupStructure
    random = createSiteFolder(portal, 'ctcc.model.servicefolder', 'Randomisation', 'random')
  File "/opt/ctcc_plone/src/ctcc.model/ctcc/model/setuphandlers.py", line 35, in createSiteFolder
    return createContentInContainer(context, type, title=title, id=id)
  File "/opt/ctcc_plone/eggs/plone.dexterity-1.1-py2.7.egg/plone/dexterity/utils.py", line 166, in createContentInContainer
    content = createContent(portal_type, **kw)
  File "/opt/ctcc_plone/eggs/plone.dexterity-1.1-py2.7.egg/plone/dexterity/utils.py", line 112, in createContent
    fti = getUtility(IDexterityFTI, name=portal_type)
  File "/opt/ctcc_plone/eggs/zope.component-3.9.5-py2.7.egg/zope/component/_api.py", line 169, in getUtility
    raise ComponentLookupError(interface, name)
ComponentLookupError: (<InterfaceClass plone.dexterity.interfaces.IDexterityFTI>, 'ctcc.model.servicefolder')
```

I'm ensuring the package's profile is imported during setup:

```py
class CTCCModelSandboxLayer(PloneSandboxLayer):
    defaultBases = (PLONE_FIXTURE,)

    def setUpZope(self, app, configurationContext):
        import ctcc.model
        self.loadZCML(package=ctcc.model)

    def setUpPloneSite(self, portal):
        self.applyProfile(portal, 'ctcc.model:default')
```

While they're listed as install requirements in the package's setup, I've also tried an explicit `applyProfile` on `plone.app.dexterity`, as well as `quickInstallProduct`, but for some reason the Dexterity FTI's don't appear to be registered at the time they're called.

I'm using Plone 4.1, Dexterity 1.1, and plone.app.testing 4.2

Comment: _Cannot_ get syntax highlighting to work on the code snippet either, sorry.

Comment: Fixed that for ya, see [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)

Comment: Ah, I was using a tag instead of a lang reference, cheers.

Comment: might it be import step ordering problem? setuphandlers.py code called before Dexterity types are installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Mikko, I moved the setuphandler configuration from the product's zcml and into a GenericSetup `import_steps.xml` instead, allowing for an explicit dependency on `typeinfo` to be specified:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<import-steps>
    <import-step
        id="ctcc-setup"
        title="Additional CTCC setup"
        handler="ctcc.model.setuphandlers.setupVarious"
        version="20120731"
    >
        <dependency step="typeinfo" />
    </import-step>
</import-steps>
```

Tests now run instead of failing during the `applyProfile` stage, and the tests of the site structure show it's being set up as expected.

Thanks again!